# which ephemeral port has java InetSocketAddress binded to?

Tags: java, sockets, java-5

**What I'd like to achieve**

bind a server to an ephemeral port for unit testing purposes.

**My issue :**

Using the 1.5.0_22 JDK I try to bind an InetSocketAddress on an ephemeral port using port 0 as per the javadoc but I can't find a way from the address object to know which port it has binded to, so I cannot have my clients configured accordingly:

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(0);
assertThat(address.isUnresolved(), is(false));
assertThat(address.getPort(), is(0));
```

I might not understand the javadoc sentence correctly :

> A valid port value is between 0 and 65535. A port number of zero will
>   let the system pick up an ephemeral port in a bind operation.

But checking the port even after having my server listening to the socket (I'm assuming the binding had happened then) does not returns anything else but 0 (the following uses the http://simpleweb.sourceforge.net/ library) :

```
    Container httpServer = new Container() {

        public void handle(Request req, Response resp) {
        }
    };
    SocketConnection connection = new SocketConnection(httpServer);
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(0);
    connection.connect(address);

    assertThat(address.isUnresolved(), is(false));
    assertThat(address.getPort(), is(0));
```

Using nmap I don't even see a binded port so I'm assuming my understanding is incorrect. Any help?

Comment: nmap works from the "outside" and is subject to firewalls and whatnot. To check for port bindings on the same machine, use "netstat" instead, which wil directly query the TCP stack, rather than poking and prodding.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `InetSocketAddress` that initially contains port 0 is not updated by `connect()` to represent the actual port that was bound to.  Call `connection.getLocalPort()` or `((InetSocketAddress)connection.getLocalSocketAddress()).getPort()` instead to get the bound port.